# Redirect Hadoop job output to a file

Tags: hadoop

Im running a Hadoop job and outputs are displayed on the console.
Is there a way for me to redirect the output to a file..I tried the below command to redirect the output but it does not work.

```
hduser@vagrant:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output>joboutput
```

Comment: *it does not work* - What does it do? Does it not make a file at `/usr/local/hadoop/joboutput`?

Comment: nope , it does not create..Is there a way to redirect the output?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the error stream to file, which is the output of hadoop job. That is use;

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output 2>joboutput
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the examples from the Hadoop homepage (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) the output will be written to

```
/user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output
```

on HDFS and not the local file system.

You can see the output via

```
hadoop fs -text /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output/*
```

And to dump that output to a local file

```
hadoop fs -text /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output/* > local.txt
```

The -text option will decompress the data so you get textual output in case you have some type of compression enabled.